# Extracting arrays from array

Tags: arrays, cell-array

I am currently working on machine learning, and as so I have an array in which the first column is the data and the second column is the label. Data was originally a cell array from Matlab (Not sure if that is important).
[My Array of arrays] https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFpWO.png

To make sure that everything is as it should be I would like to extract one of the arrays in index 0 and check its dimensions with the numpy.shape function. Currently, if I try that I just get the shape of the bigger array IE. (394,2)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways.: Try..

```
arr[:,1,:]
```

or

```
arr[:,1]
```

or

```
[a[1] for a in arr]
```

Comment: Yes i know that the bigger array is 394 rows and two columns. 
My question is how to extract the array from within the bigger array so I can check the shape of that array :)